# Intersection of two left cosets is empty

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have $\theta,\tau, \sigma\in S_7$, where $\theta=(13)(14)(567), \tau=(137)(2456), 
\sigma=(13456)(27)$. I need to find $\sigma \langle\theta\rangle\cap\tau\langle\theta\rangle$.

I approached this by first computing $\langle\theta\rangle$. I got $\langle\theta\rangle=\{(13)(24)(567),(576),(13)(24),(675),(13)(24)(576),id\}$.

I then worked out the left coset $\sigma\langle\theta\rangle$ by multiplying $(13456)(27)$ by every  element in $\langle\theta\rangle$, one by one. That gave me $\{(1574632),(134726),(274563),(1346)(257),(263)(457)\}$.

Using the same technique, I found $\tau\langle\theta\rangle$ to be $\{(357)(46),(136247),(37)(456),(1357)(246),(3647),id\}$.

But then I get $\sigma\langle\theta\rangle\cap\tau\langle\theta\rangle=\phi$, since there are no elements occurring in both $\sigma\langle\theta\rangle$ and $\tau\langle\theta\rangle$.

Why is the intersection empty? If I have done this right, is there an easier way to tell that the intersection of two cosets will be empty, without having to work out each individual result (since that is tedious)?

Comment: Do you recall the fact that two left cosets are either equal or disjoint? (True for any group and subgroup.)

Answer (score 4):

Left (or right) cosets of a subgroup $\;H\;$ in a group $\;G\;$ are in fact *equivalence classes*, the equivalence relation $\;\sim\;$ on $\;G\;$ being:

$$\text{For}\;x,y\in G\;,\;\; x\sim y\iff x^{-1}y\in H$$

We usually write $\;xH=yH\;$ instead of $\;x\sim y\;$ . Check this is in fact an equivalence relation, and then we know two equivalence classes are either identical or else they're disjoint, and this just means $\;xH = yH\;\;\text{or}\;\;xH\cap yH=\emptyset\;$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is standard. Given two left cosets of the same subgroup, either they're the same as sets, or they don't intersect at all.

As such, all we need to do to find that two cosets of a subgroup are disjoint is to find a single element of one coset that's not in the other coset. An example that comes up fairly often: if $a$ is not an element of the subgroup $H$, the coset $aH$ doesn't intersect $H$.